# R replacing names in a dataset

Tags: r, replace, dataset

I have this R script for data mining:

```
`FAO_AreaName <-"TLS"
news_url <-   paste0("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/common/allnews/en/?iso3=", FAO_AreaName,"&allnews=no&limit=2")
news <- fromJSON(news_url)
title <- news[3]
date <- news[6]
FAO_AreaName_1 <- news[5]
content_TLS <- news[5]
TLS <- cbind(FAO_AreaName, FAO_AreaName_1, date, title, content_TLS)
```

`

In this example, TLS stands for "Timor-Leste".
I am using the following packages:
rvest,
stringr,
tidyr,
data.table,
plyr,
xml2,
selectr,
tibble,
purrr,
datapasta,
jsonlite.

In any case, I have a long .csv list of country name codes (e.g. USA, ISR, ITA, etc) I should replace to TLS to complete the script. 
Any suggestion before starting replacing manually?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a function:

```
do_my_task <- function(FAO_AreaName) {
    news_url <-   paste0("http://www.fao.org/countryprofiles/common/allnews/en/?iso3=", FAO_AreaName,"&allnews=no&limit=2")
    news <- fromJSON(news_url)
    title <- news[3]
    date <- news[6]
    FAO_AreaName_1 <- news[5]
    content_TLS <- news[5]
    cbind(FAO_AreaName, FAO_AreaName_1, date, title, content_TLS)
}


areas <- c("TLS", "USA", ...)
my_datasets <- lapply(areas, do_my_task)
```

Comment: This is giving the following error:

`Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : parse error: premature EOF
                                       
                     (right here) ------^
Called from: parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char)
Browse[1]> `

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the web file read inside the `fromJSON` call.